# Is it possible to export/import all connections within SSIS?

Tags: ssis

Does SSIS 2012 allow to export all connections of a project for a further import into another project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's import/export connections utility in SSIS. You could, however, create package configuration file and include your connection managers in it. Then you can edit the file to run your package on different environment, or use values in it to update configuration file of another package.

resource:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141132.aspx

Comment: Ok but what if my connections are global (I mean scope is "project" and not "package")?

Comment: @davidloubere I don't know if you can make one configuration file project-wide. Rather not. Maybe parsing DTSX code is a way out.

Answer (score 3):

In 2012 SSIS projects, you now have 2 options. The classic, pre 2012 way which is referred to as Package Deployment Model. The new, default, model is the Project Deployment Model. This answer focuses on the Project Deployment model.

Before you begin any manual edits of files, use a version control system. While you *can* edit XML by hand, you need to have a safe recovery point in case you pooch the files.

In SSIS 2012, you can have Connection Managers scoped to packages as you've always done or they can now be a shared, project wide connection. Project connection managers show up in every package in SSDT, whether you need them or not. They are prefaced with `(project)`.

If you've created a package Connection Manager that you wish to make into a project resource, simply right click on the CM and select `Convert to Project Connection`.

One caveat if you reverse that, the `Convert to Package Connection` is only going to create that CM in the current package. That's not such a hassle when it's 2 or 3 packages, but when it's 20ish, that gets tedious.

A Project Connection Manager has a physical file associated with it. In your project's folder, there will be .conmgr file for each connection manager. That defines the connection all the packages share. However, packages only "know" about the connection manager because of data in the .dtproj file.

If I wanted to re-use an existing project connection manager in a new project, I'd need to copy that file into my new projects folder. After that, I'd have to edit the .dtproj file and add that file's name in between the ConnectionManagers tag

```
  <DeploymentModelSpecificContent>
    <Manifest>
        ...
        <SSIS:ConnectionManagers>
          <SSIS:ConnectionManager SSIS:Name="PackageCM.conmgr" />
        </SSIS:ConnectionManagers>
```

Now when SSDT opens the project file up, you should have a project CM exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the connection. Copy the connection Manager and paste in required package

[image: Screenshot]